# jqGrid Selecting multiple Rows

Tags: jqgrid

Is it possible that a user clicks on a row in the jqGrid and it triggers off onSelectRow which is normal behavior. Also I need the functionality if a user uses "Control + click" then it marks the row as selected (for print& excel export) but does not trigger onSelectRow.

Comment: @Oleg you may be able to help me on this...

Comment: If you want to post me a message you should write comment to any my *previous answer* (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/147495) for details). The usage of "@Oleg" on the page where no answer or comment from me exist can't be resolved. If you [search for the name Oleg](http://stackoverflow.com/users?search=oleg) you will find many users with the alias.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to highlight some rows to create a screenshot, for the demonstration purpose or for printing you can use `beforeSelectRow` to implement the behaviour which you need:

```js
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var $tr;
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        $tr = $(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow');
        if ($tr.hasClass("ui-state-highlight")) {
            $tr.removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
        } else {
            $tr.addClass("ui-state-highlight");
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HighlightRowsForPrinting.htm):

[image]

I should mention, that in the demo I used additionally `disableSelection` method used internally by jQuery UI to prevent selection of the texts in the grid.

Comment: +1 Code can be simplified by removing the `if ($tr.hasClass("ui-state-highlight"))` block and replacing with `$tr.toggleClass("ui-state-highlight");`